# Unir posición de index de un array cuando se hace loop

Tags: javascript

Necesito un poco de ayuda con algo que espero no sea tan difícil de solventar.

Tengo estos arreglos:

```
var init_ProductVitrina = [

[2284502,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT01","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], ["296242X","ID-CATEGORIA","CAT02","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], [3497038,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT03","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], ["324928X","ID-CATEGORIA","CAT04","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], [3008673,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT05","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], [3435210,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT06","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"]];

var init_ProductCarrusel = [

["2299062C","MARCA-SKU"], ["296242X","MARCA-SKU"], [3497038,"MARCA-SKU"], ["324928X","MARCA-SKU"], [3008673,"MARCA-SKU"], [3435210,"MARCA-SKU"]];
```

A continuación hago una función para hacer `loop` en ellos y encontrar el elemento en `posición[0]`.

```
function skuPull(listaskuVit,listaskuCarr) {
    for (i = 0; i < listaskuVit.length && listaskuCarr.length; i++) {
        sku = [];
        skuList = sku.push(listaskuVit[i][0] && listaskuCarr[i][0]);
        console.log('Array de sku: ' + skuList);
    }
}

skuPull(init_ProductVitrina,init_ProductCarrusel);
```

Lo que quiero lograr es unir ambos elementos encontrados en `posición[0]` de ambos arreglos en un solo arreglo.

Actualmente esto me esta imprimiendo esto:

**Array de sku: 1**

y necesito que haga esto:

```
Array de sku:[2284502,"296242X",3497038,"324928X",3008673,3435210,"2299062C","296242X",3497038,"324928X",3008673,343521]
```

Soy nuevo en `Javascript`, pero hasta ahora este ha sido uno de mis mas grandes problemas...

Cualquiera que pueda ayudarme se lo agradezco en el alma...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no reconozco el operando `&&` entre dos tamaños de arreglos, en javascript ese operando es usado para booleanos por lo que el resultado de `listaskuVit.length && listaskuCarr.length` te dará true o false

ahora la línea:

```
skuList = sku.push(listaskuVit[i][0] && listaskuCarr[i][0]);
```

esta te comparará ambos valores dentro de los arreglos (listas) y probablemente de retorne `true` por como funciona javascript. Lo que creo que quieres hacer es lo siguiente, crear una variable sku que es un arreglo de los valores en la posición *i*, en cada posición hay un arreglo asi que concatenamos estos en la variable *sku* lo que generará un arreglo a partir de los arreglos que se encuentras dentro de los arreglos pasados como parámetros y la imprimimos a consola, te dejo este código para que lo pruebes

```
function skuPull(listaskuVit,listaskuCarr) {
    for (i = 0; i < Math.min(listaskuVit.length, listaskuCarr.length); i++) {
        sku = listaskuVit[i].contac(listaskuCarr[i]);
        console.log('Array de sku: ' + sku);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración me sirvió muchísimo...

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que dice @LPZadkiel es totalmente cierto en la conclusión, para ello debes modificar un poco la lógica, el código que tienes. A continuación te dejo una posible solución no se que tan factible sea para ti, también soy nuevo en `javascript`, pero yo lo haría de esta manera, espero que te funcione, pueden haber mejores soluciones.

```js
var init_ProductVitrina = [

    [2284502,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT01","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], 
    ["296242X","ID-CATEGORIA","CAT02","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], 
    [3497038,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT03","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], 
    ["324928X","ID-CATEGORIA","CAT04","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], 
    [3008673,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT05","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"], 
    [3435210,"ID-CATEGORIA","CAT06","MARCA-PRODUCTO","MARCA-CATEGORIA"]
];

var init_ProductCarrusel = [

    ["2299062C","MARCA-SKU"], 
    ["296242X","MARCA-SKU"], 
    [3497038,"MARCA-SKU"], 
    ["324928X","MARCA-SKU"], 
    [3008673,"MARCA-SKU"], 
    [3435210,"MARCA-SKU"]
];

function skuPull(listaskuVit,listaskuCarr) {
        arrListaskuVit = [];
        arrListaskuCarr = [];
        item1 = listaskuVit.map(function(obj1) {
            arrListaskuVit.push(obj1[0]);
        });
        item2 = listaskuCarr.map(function(obj2){
            arrListaskuCarr.push(obj2[0]);
        })
        console.log(arrListaskuVit.concat(arrListaskuCarr));
    }
skuPull(init_ProductVitrina,init_ProductCarrusel);
```

Comment: Excelente, funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias...

Comment: @Reezppo Con mucho gusto, si la respuesta te fue útil también recuerda marcarla dándole **CLICK** a la flecha hacia arriba, recuerda que en SOes estamos para contribuir, brindando las mejores soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que más te serviría es utilizar otro 'for' adentro del que ya tienes, algo parecido a esto:

```
var arr = [["h","o"],["p","a"]];
var arr_2 = [["l","a"],["p","a"]];
var auxarr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
    auxarr.push(arr[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length;j++){
        auxarr[i] += arr_2[i][j];
    }
}
```